# How to determine the View receiving focus during onFocusChange event

Tags: android, focus

I have an `Activity` with rows of ViewGroups each with multiple `EditText` views.  I need to detect when the user clicks to a new row or another area of the screen or hits escape to dismiss the keyboard so no view has focus.  The appearance of the "row" changes depending on whether any of the child views is focused or none of the children are focused.  Lost focus events are sent before focused events so `parent.getFocusedChild()` is not helpful. Is there a way to know which view is about to receive focus from the editText's `OnFocusChangeListener`?

Comment: same problem as mine, did u get anything till now or not ??